# Smartphone input voltage range

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I've cobbled together a solar panel charger that outputs 10V @1.5Ah.

The manual for the Samsung S8+ recommends charging at 9V 1.67A or 5V 2A. I ended up contacting Samsung Support to see if they knew more details on the voltage input range and whether there is any leeway in that 9V recommendation.

I wasn't too shocked to hear the support fellow reading out the manual verbatim that it should be charged at 9V only.

My understanding is that almost every smartphone contains a charging circuits to regulate overcharging, overdischarging, etc.

Could anyone clarify or confirm what range of voltages from a DC power supply to a modern smartphone is fine before you start causing damage to the device?

Comment: Are you asking here for advise against the ratings provided by a user manual? I think noone will...

Comment: @Huisman No, he couldn't find a 5.000000V adapter

Comment: If you just want to quickly get a working solar charger – get a 5V switch-mode buck converter rated at 2A and use it to convert your solar panel output to stable 5V. It will be efficient and cheap if you buy from China.

Answer (score 2):

Samsung S8+ uses [Quick Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge) 2.0 spec, as evidenced by page 12 of [QC device list](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/quick-charge-device-list.pdf). 
Quick Charge is a proprietary protocol that doesn't immediately provide voltages above 5V to a client device. Instead, the client device starts charging at 5V and negotiates higher voltage/power by requesting it from a charger. Charger should only provide higher voltage to a client device after negotiation. It is possible to implement the Quick Charge negotiation by "bitbanging" the protocol, see https://hackaday.com/2016/12/13/bitbanging-qualcomm-charge-controllers/

You're at risk of damaging your phone if trying to directly charge it with 9V without implementing the QC protocol first, because the phone really expects the charger to be at 5V at the moment of connecting.

Comment: Beautiful answer! Just to make sure I understand you correctly, QC protocol will always asks for 5V 2A initially but after certain conditions are met within the client, the client will decide to use an on-board boost converter to go from 5V 2A to 9V 1.67A which enables Quick Charge?

Comment: @Drow3515 there’s no up-converting on client side: at the moment of connecting charger, it outputs 5V. Then the client asks charger to provide higher voltage, and if charger is able to do so – it acknowledges the request and increases the output voltage.